# Prefix every argument with -o in BASH

Tags: bash, function

How do I prefix `-p` to every argument passed to my function?

Modifying the arguments themselves and creating a new array are both fine.

Comment: Why do you need that?

Comment: @alex: For `pgrep` and subsequently `strace`. i.e. to strace a bunch of processes, given their names.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should work nicely even for complicated arguments with whitespace and worse:

```
#!/bin/bash
new_args=()
for arg
do
    new_args+=( '-p' )
    new_args+=( "$arg" )
done

for arg in "${new_args[@]}"
do
    echo "$arg"
done
```

Test:

```
$ ~/test.sh foo $'bar\n\tbaz bay'
-p
foo
-p
bar
    baz bay
```

Comment: That looks like it's what I need, but unfortunately I can't figure out how to get it to work for a *function*, rather than script (which is what you have). Any ideas?

Comment: Just cut and paste the whole thing in an `argparse() { ... }` function block - It works just fine here.

Comment: Well I think I was actually having a problem with using `xargs` on the function, but it's fixed now; thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can preserve the spaces in the `${ARGS[@]/#/-p }` expansion if you set the `IFS` variable to a null string!

```
# sample code
(
set -- 1 2 3 'arg with spaces' $'bar\n\tbaz bay'
printf 'oldIFS: %q\n' "$IFS"
IFS=""                       
#IFS=" "                       
printf 'newIFS: %q\n' "$IFS"
ARGS=("$@")
ARGS=( ${ARGS[@]/#/-p } )
for ((i=0; i < ${#ARGS[@]}; i++)); do
  echo "$i: ${ARGS[i]}"
done
)
```

Inside a function you may limit the scope of a modified `IFS` variable to this function by using `declare IFS=""`.

Answer (score 1):

Put the arguments in an array and use [bash pattern substitution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) on them with array substitution and prefix matching:

```
ARGS=("$@")
echo ${ARGS[@]/#/-p }
```

That replaces the start of each arg with `-p<space>`.

Unfortunately this does not work properly if you have spaces in your arguments. Spaces are preserved properly with `ARGS=("$@")`, but not when you do the `${ARGS[@]/#/-p }` expansion. You can put double quotes around that expansion, but then you get `-p arg1` as a single argument, not two arguments.

If you don't need `-p<space>` prepended, just `-p` then putting double quotes around the expansion should work fine. Experiment with and without double quotes around the expansion to see what works best for you.